# Integrals with fractions as limits and display modes

Tags: math-mode, pdftex, amsmath, texstudio, displaystyle

I would like to learn how auto-program my document to display integrals with fractions nicely.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

$\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{10}} \frac{x^2+x+1}{e^x +3}$ \vspace{1cm}

$\frac{x^2+x+1}{e^x+\frac{3}{2}}$ \vspace{1cm}

\end{document}
```

The result of the above MWE is :
[image: Integral with fractions as limit "not so nice display"]
[image: Fraction without integrals "not so nice display"]

What I would like to know is how do I program it so that if you have a limits with fractions use \tfrac for the limits but if you have a fraction on it own, use \dfrac.

Desired result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

$\displaystyle\int_{\tfrac{1}{2}}^{\tfrac{\pi}{10}} \dfrac{x^2+x+1}{e^x +3}$ \vspace{1cm}

$\dfrac{x^2+x+1}{e^x+\dfrac{3}{2}}$ \vspace{1cm}

\end{document}
```

[image: Desired Result]

Any direction/advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: With only few exceptions, using `\dfrac` in the denominator (or numerator) of a `\dfrac` expression is bound to look *preposterous*. (The present case isn't one of those exceptions...) Do you have a reason for not using inline-fraction notation, i.e., for not writing `\frac{x^2+x+1}{e^x+3/2}`? On a related subject, have you considered writing either `\int_{1/2}^{\pi/10}` or `\int_{0.5}^{0.1\pi}`?

Comment: I need it to look nice, that why i avoid using the inline \frac. As for using ```\int_{1/2}^{\pi/10} or \int_{0.5}^{0.1\pi}``` it doesn't look nice.

Comment: So `\dfrac{3}{2}` in the denominator looks nicer than `3/2`. As the old saying goes, there's no arguing about taste...

Comment: ```\frac{3}{2}``` in the denominator looks crammed. What about the fraction in the integrals? ```\dfrac{x}{y}``` makes it look big.

Comment: It does *not* follow from "`\frac{3}{2}`in the denominator looks cram[p]ed" that the best remedy is to use `\dfrac{3}{2}` in the denominator. Do compare, say, the outputs of `\dfrac{x^2+x+1}{e^x+\frac{3}{2}}`, `\dfrac{x^2+x+1}{e^x+\frac{3\mathstrut}{2}}`, and `\dfrac{x^2+x+1}{e^x+\dfrac{3}{2}}`.

Comment: My problem is how do i program the document to toggle between say using ```\tfrac{}{}``` when it is used in the limits of an integral sign and use ```\dfrac{}{}``` when it used as an ordinary fraction (algebraic or otherwise), I don't want to manually change them.